# How to link unique URLs to a number of images that fade in and out

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm new to coding and to this site. 
I have a mysql database that allows me to add images and a link to a URL. On my website these images fade in and out and what I want to be able to do is, when I hover over the image I can click on it and it should take me to the URL that is sorted in the mysql database for it.

The Code I have so far only does the fading in a out, I need it to somehow pick up the relevant ID for the image and then assign the corresponding URL link to it.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

```
<?php if($imgfading) { ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
          $('#imgfading').cycle({
            fx:      'fade', 
            speed:    1700,
            timeout: 2000
        });
       });
   </script>

   <div id="imgfading">
   <?php while($row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($imgresult)) { 
       $fln = "imgfading/FAD".$row['id'].".JPG";
       if(file_exists($fln)) {
          echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'"><img src="'.$fln.'" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Featured in" border="0" />';
          echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'"</a>';}
       }
} ?>
```

Comment: let me get this .... does it mean `$row['link']` is empty or now showing the proper link ?? Can you try and put your expected result and what you are having now

Comment: this line `echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'"</a>';` is missing its closing `>` have you tried changing the href to `href="'.$fln.'"`?

Comment: Dear Baba - I have a picture which I upload into my CMS system and the code above fetches it for me i.e. $fln = "imgfading/FAD".$row['id'].".JPG"; I want it to fetch the corresponding weblink I have for this picture as well. I guess the code will need to be changed to include the $row['id'] of the picture so it knows which website to pick up when that picture is showing on my website. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Dear Lawrence - Thank you for you comment and for spotting the missing </a> :). If I change it to href="'.$fln.'" then it links to where my pictures are saved i.e.  $fln = "imgfading/FAD".$row['id'].".JPG". As mentioned above to Baba, I think the code may need to be changed so it includes the $row['id'] somehow ? Thanks for your help.